# Cypress Cucumber, how Get to data from page in one step and use it another scenario step

Tags: javascript, cypress, mocha.js, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

In one scenario I'm getting data from page and saving it in a variable as an alias.
Then I want to use the same variable/data in another scenario, to type into an `<input>` field. I'm getting this error:

> `cy.wait()` could not find a registered alias for `@Orderinfo`.
> You have not aliased anything yet.*

The data is stored in `@Orderinfo` but is not accessible in the other scenario step.

```js
Then("Get Data from page", () => {
  cy.get(".os-order-number").invoke("text").then(($Oid) => {
    let Order = $Oid.text();
    let Order_id = Order.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    cy.wrap(Order_id).as("Orderinfo");
  });
});


Given("Go to Login", () => {
  cy.visit("https://dev.simplifyshopping.com/register/");
});

When("Paste variable here", () => {
  cy.wait(2000);
  cy.wait("@Orderinfo")
  cy.get("@Orderinfo")).then((Orderinfo) => {
    console.log(Orderinfo);
    cy.get("#id_email").type(Orderinfo);
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you really want to access the variable from a different scenario (i.e. a different test)? Or do you just want to access it in another step of the same scenario?

Comment: @SebastianoVierk First I have to use in same scenario within differentSteps. But for future I have to use in other Scenario's too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So both, the use across several steps of the same scenario, as well as scenario overlapping are possible with Cypress using Cucumber Preprocessor.

**1. Use of values across multiple steps of the same scenario**

Referring to the example from the question, the `Order_Id` can be defined outside the steps and is thus accessible in the global scope from all steps. If I understood the code correctly, it would be something like this (probably unnecessary code commented out):

```
let Order_id;

Then("Get Data from page", () => {
  cy.get(".os-order-number").invoke("text").then(($Oid) => {
    let Order = $Oid.text();
    Order_id = Order.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    // cy.wrap(Order_id).as("Orderinfo");
  });
});


Given("Go to Login", () => {
  cy.visit("https://dev.simplifyshopping.com/register/");
});

When("Paste variable here", () => {
  cy.wait(2000);
  // cy.wait("@Orderinfo")
  // cy.get("@Orderinfo")).then((Orderinfo) => {
  //  console.log(Orderinfo);
  //  cy.get("#id_email").type(Orderinfo);
  // });

  console.log(Order_id);
  cy.get("#id_email").type(Order_id);
});
```

**2. Use of values across scenarios (hold state across tests)**

To make certain values accessible across the execution of different scenarios, for example, a `helper.js` file can be created containing the following code:

```
export const stateStore = {};
```

Inside your step definition files, you can then import the `stateStore` and fill it with values as you like:

```
import { Given, When } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';
import { stateStore } from '../helpers';

// step used in first scenario
Given('some value is made available in scenario 1', () => {
  stateStore.someValue = 'this is a value';
});

// step used in second scenario
When('this value can be used in another step of scneario 2', () => {
  console.log(`Print some value: ${stateStore.someValue}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using "alias" .as in cypress. Store variable .as("vaiableName") and then access it in required function as this.variableName. It could be like this.

```
Then("Get Data from page", function () {
    cy.get(".os-order-number").then($Oid => {
        const Order = $Oid.text()
        const Order_id = Order.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
        cy.log("inside Then function" + Order_id)
        cy.wrap(Order_id).as("wrapText")
    })
})

Given("Go to Login", function () {

    cy.log(this.wrapText)
})
```